# Checking whether the String contains multiple words

Tags: java

I am getting the names as String. How can I display in the following format: If it's single word, I need to display the first character alone. If it's two words, I need to display the first two characters of the word.

```
John : J
Peter: P
Mathew Rails : MR
Sergy Bein : SB
```

I cannot use an `enum` as I am not sure that the list would return the same values all the time. Though they said, it's never going to change.

```
String name = myString.split('');
topTitle = name[0].subString(0,1);
subTitle = name[1].subString(0,1);
String finalName = topTitle + finalName;
```

The above code fine, but its not working. I am not getting any exception either.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Everything's fine, except, your name should be an array. `String#split` returns an array. Well, how did that code even compile?

Comment: Should it not be substring() instead of subString(), every answer also has the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your attempted code.

1. `String#split` takes a String as regex.
2. Return value of `String#split` is an array of String.

so it should be:

```
String[] name = myString.split(" ");
```

or

```
String[] name = myString.split("\\s+);
```

You also need to check for # of elements in array first like this to avoid exception:

```
String topTitle, subTitle;
if (name.length == 2) {
   topTitle = name[0].subString(0,1);
   subTitle = name[1].subString(0,1);
}
else
   topTitle = name.subString(0,1);
```

Comment: You have to check if name[1] and name[0] are not null though, because he said "If it's single word, I need to display the first character alone."

Comment: @JREN: I'm checking `name.length == 2` to make sure that.

Answer (score 0):

The `String.split` method split a string into an array of strings, based on your regular expression.

This should work:

```
String[] names = myString.split("\\s+");
String topTitle = names[0].subString(0,1);
String subTitle = names[1].subString(0,1);
String finalName = topTitle + finalName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close..

```
 String[] name = myString.split(" ");
 String finalName = name[0].charAt(0)+""+(name.length==1?"":name[1].charAt(0));
```

`(name.length==1?"":name[1].charAt(0))` is a ternary operator which would return empty string if length of name array is 1 else it would return 1st character

Comment: You have to check if name[1] and name[0] are not null though, because he said "If it's single word, I need to display the first character alone."

Comment: You should also explain how a ternary operator works, if the OP doesn't know what it is, he won't choose yours as best answer, because he doesn't know what `name.size()==1?"":name[1].charAt(0)` means

Comment: @JREN no need to check it..split would return a single string if there's no space..rest is taken care by the ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

First: "name" should be an array.

```
String[] names = myString.split(" ");
```

Second: You should use an if function and the `length` variable to determine the length of a variable.

```
String initial = "";
if(names.length > 1){
    initial = names[0].subString(0,1) + names[1].subString(0,1);
}else{
    initial = names[0].subString(0,1);
}
```

Alternatively you could use a for loop

```
String initial = "";
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    initial += names[i].subString(0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
public static void getString(String str) throws IOException {
    String[] strr=str.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<strr.length;i++){
        sb.append(strr[i].charAt(0));
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```